# Convert a String to a System.Color in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to make this application on VB.NET in which the user can change the background color of the application, when the application closes the color should save to a XML. The saving was piece of cake but now the real dilemma is how to convert the String `"Color[white]"` to a `System.Color`.

I already Googled my problem but no result. Plus I'm already familiar to `Color.FromName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim C = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(YourColorString.Replace("Color[" , "").Replace("]", ""))
```

Answer (score 7):

Are you familiar with `Color.FromName`? That should do it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname(v=vs.110).aspx

`Dim slateBlue As Color = Color.FromName("SlateBlue")`

@dotNet's answer has an example on how to parse out just the name. If you can optionally have a color value stored as red, green, blue, and alpha values, then there is also `Color.FromArgb`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh(v=vs.110).aspx

`Dim red As Color = Color.FromArgb(alpha, 255, 0, 0)`

*Edit...* @Plutonix also has an interesting suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar to Color.FromName but as you see my string is not always the name of a color. Example of what could be "Color[A=255, R=0, G=54, B=234]"

Comment: @user2895707 This fact should have unquestionably been included in the original question.  ESPECIALLY if you're already familiar with `Color.FromName`.

Comment: @user2895707 Well, my answer is then not so relevant if what you're trying to do is to parse the value depending on the format. You should elaborate on this in your question.

Answer (score 5):

Just for future "searchers" There is a color.Toargb and color.Fromargb which converts into, and out, of an integer which is serializable.

Comment: This is exactly what I need - glad I took the time to read through all the responses!

Answer (score 4):

If you save a colour which isn't one of the named colours, it writes it in the format `Color [A=99, R=99, G=19, B=255]`. You can parse your string for that too:

```
Option Infer On
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
' ...
''' <summary>
''' Convert a string of the format "color [nameOfColor]" or
''' "color [A=a, R=r, G=g, B=b]" to a System.Drawing.Color.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="s">A String representing the colour.</param>
''' <returns>A System.Drawing.Color.</returns>
''' <remarks>Returns fallbackColour if the colour could not be parsed.</remarks>
Public Shared Function ColourFromData(s As String) As Color
    Dim fallbackColour = Color.Black

    If Not s.StartsWith("color", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
        Return fallbackColour
    End If

    ' Extract whatever is between the brackets.
    Dim re = New Regex("\[(.+?)]")
    Dim colorNameMatch = re.Match(s)
    If Not colorNameMatch.Success Then
        Return fallbackColour
    End If

    Dim colourName = colorNameMatch.Groups(1).Value

    ' Get the names of the known colours.
    'TODO: If this function is called frequently, consider creating allColours as a variable with a larger scope.
    Dim allColours = [Enum].GetNames(GetType(System.Drawing.KnownColor))

    ' Attempt a case-insensitive match to the known colours.
    Dim nameOfColour = allColours.FirstOrDefault(Function(c) String.Compare(c, colourName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0)

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(nameOfColour) Then
        Return Color.FromName(nameOfColour)
    End If

    ' Was not a named colour. Parse for ARGB values.
    re = New Regex("A=(\d+).*?R=(\d+).*?G=(\d+).*?B=(\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim componentMatches = re.Match(colourName)

    If componentMatches.Success Then

        Dim a = Integer.Parse(componentMatches.Groups(1).Value)
        Dim r = Integer.Parse(componentMatches.Groups(2).Value)
        Dim g = Integer.Parse(componentMatches.Groups(3).Value)
        Dim b = Integer.Parse(componentMatches.Groups(4).Value)

        Dim maxValue = 255

        If a > maxValue OrElse r > maxValue OrElse g > maxValue OrElse b > maxValue Then
            Return fallbackColour
        End If

        Return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b)

    End If

    Return fallbackColour

End Function
```

You could throw a FormatException instead of returning a fall-back value if you wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

Especially when serializing, it is often worthwhile to make the process agnostic - it ought not care whether it is an ARGB string or named color.  And for that matter, it can be made to not care whether it is a Font, Point, Size, Color or Rectangle.  Just use the Converter procedures built into .NET.  (Note: your color name looks irregular, this depends on NET handling the To and From):

```
_text = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(v.GetType).ConvertToInvariantString(v)
```

This will give you a string that can be converted back to a font, point, rectangle etc, depending on what type `v` is.  To get back the object:

```
myColor = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(System.Drawing.Color)) _ 
              .ConvertFromInvariantString(_text)
```

If you wrap it in a function using a generic, it can be able to unpack agnostically  as well:

```
 Function ConvertMyThing(Of T)(text as String) As T

    return CType(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(T)) _ 
              .ConvertFromInvariantString(text), T)
 End Function
```

Usage:

```
  myColor = ConvertMyThing(Of Color)(colorString)
```

`ConvertToInvariantString` is **not** the same as `ToString`.  `ToString` makes debug/human friendly text like `Color [A=99, R=99, G=19, B=255]` or similar for Point, Size etc.  The color output from `ConvertToInvariantString` would simply be `99, 19, 255` (it apparently omits `A` if it is 255).

For Color, it is great because there is no parsing required, no RegEx, no Splitting, Joining, no fuss and no muss.  As a bonus it will handle Point, Font, Rectangle, Size, Decimal...  System.Enum is more trouble than Font.

Comment: You forgot the CType: `Return CType(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(T)).ConvertFromString(text), T)`. Also, I can't figure out how to get it to convert a Color written in ARGB format, e.g. `"Color [A=99, R=99, G=19, B=255]"`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton   yes, I did...the output from ConvertToInvariantString for color is just `23, 122, 250` same for point etc.  its the decorations from simple `.ToString` that makes is readable but also then must be parsed. thats why I mentioned using ConvertTO AND From together, cant mix them with ToString or a roll-your-own method

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. It's a bit of a shame it doesn't work with the values generated by .ToString(). Incidentally, both three- and four-component colours work.

Answer (score 0):

If this is winforms why don't you use My.settings (click on my project in the solution explorer, click on the settings tab,create a new setting of type system.drawing.color with scope set to user).  You can assign the background colour of a form or forms to use the relevant setting (in the properties for the form open up application settings, click on property bindings and in the dialog that pops up assign BackColour to the setting you created).

Make sure on application close you save the settings (My.Settings.save).  Whatever the end user selects as a colour will be saved between sessions.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an old question, but, an answer is always useful: When extracting the color, pick it up as RGB (it's easier to convert it back). For example, you could use :
    Dim S AS String = ctrl.BackColor.ToArgb.ToString

to get it back, you should use: 
    ctrl.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(CInt(S))
In this case, You don't have to just serialize it : The property can be extracted to a text, a memoryFile, used in XML Or any other Cases (when you need to put this setting in a "delimeterd" line, and parsing it later to get this color back)
Nevertheless, this BackColor  as described in your question is more like a setting, so, consider using My.Settings and save it before closing as described in the answer of Dom Sinclair (above), this could be a better approach

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim AAA as string = "AAA"
    
Dim color As String
    
color = "<strong style='color:red'>(" & AAA & ")</strong>"
```

If you put the string "AAA" in a label you will see that label colored red.

e.g.

```vb
Label.Text = AAA
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 8 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.