# Convert String to Color in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

this is my idea:
while exiting the form it saves the backcolor to a file that is located in the temp that is called settings.txt.
next time you open the form it will check if the file exists and if it is it will take what is written in there (the backcolor) and will change it to the current form backcolor.
i'm having a problem while importing the text that written in the settings.txt to the backcolor.

```
    Dim fileReader As String
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(TempDirectory + "/Settings.txt")
    System.Drawing.Color.FromName = fileReader.ToString
```

I'm having a blue line under:

```
System.Drawing.Color.FromName
```

When i move my mouse to it, it shows

> Argument not specified for parameter 'name' of 'Public Shared Function FromName(name As String) As System.Drawing.Color.'

By the way in the settings.txt written

> Color [Lime]

Any suggestions anyone?

**Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition**

Comment: Are you parsing out and using "Lime" from "Color [Lime]" ?

Comment: Consider using project settings instead of a text file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Designer_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsDesigner);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true

Comment: @JerryM my teacher wants me to work with files

Answer (score 3):

System.Drawing.Color is not the sort of thing to which you would assign a value.  Wherever you're looking to set the color, I think you want something more like

```
SomeObject.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Lime")
```

So, to read it from that variable, you might need something like:

```
SomeObject.color = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(fileReader.Replace("Color[").Replace("]"))
```

Those `.Replace` functions are to get rid of the extraneous characters in the file.

Answer (score 2):

**Convert String to Color**

To convert a string to a `Color`, you can use either of these options:

- [`Color.FromName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`ColorConverter.ConvertFromString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606533(v=vs.110).aspx)

Both of them are in `System.Drawing.dll`. Make sure you have a reference to `System.Drawing` dll.

Both of them are in `System.Drawing` namespace. Don't forget to `Imports System.Drawing`.

`ColorConverter` parse both name and RGB representation:

```
Dim color1 = color.FromName("Red")
Dim color2 = DirectCast(New ColorConverter().ConvertFromString("Red"), Color)
Dim color3 = DirectCast(New ColorConverter().ConvertFromString("255,0,0"), Color)
```

**Problem In Your Code**

The problem in your code is you didn't pass the name to `FromName` method. If you want to fix your code you will find answer of [Steve Barron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34683880/3110834) useful.

**Other option that may help you**

If you want to store some colors as setting, it's better to use `Settings.settings` file under `My Project` and add some settings, by specifing a `Name` and `System.Drawing.Color` as `Type` and `User` as `Scope` and select a color for `Value`. Then you can simply use (read, assign, save, reset) those settings using `My.Settings`.

It also supports [property binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wabtadw6(v=vs.100).aspx) as mentioned by [Andrew Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34684220/3110834) and you will find his answer useful. This way you can select your control at design time, then in property grid, under `(ApplicationSettings)` click `...` for `(PropertyBinding)` and from the dialog, bind the properties you need to the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing code to do that, you can use a Property Binding in the Application Settings.

1. Select the form (i.e. not any of its sub-controls) in the designer view.
2. Bring up the Properties windows (e.g. press <kbd>F4</kbd>).
3. Click the "Properties" tab (in case you are in the "Events" tag).
4. Expand the "(ApplicationSettings)" section and click on "(PropertyBinding)".
5. Click the ellipsis button in the second column (you may have to hover over it to the right to see the button).
6. In the dialog which appears, find "BackColor" and click in the column to the right of it where it says "(none)".
7. From the dropdown, choose "New...".
8. Enter a sensible name for the setting, and choose a "DefaultValue" if you want to.
9. OK out of that.

Now when you run your program it will automatically set the BackColor of the form to whatever it was on the previous run.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I was writing that answer, unaware of the MSDN article, while you were adding your comment - which I subsequently upvoted:)

Comment: that is a good way but my teacher wants me to work with files

Answer (score 0):

If  you write only one color in setting.txt than you have only one mistake

```
 Dim fileReader As String
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(TempDirectory +  "/Settings.txt")
    System.Drawing.Color.FromName(fileReader)
```

And in settings.txt should be written only "Lime" not "Color[Lime]" (without quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Alright now its working and this is what i did:

At the start:

```
Dim TempDirectory As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp
```

when closing:

```
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(TempDirectory + "/Settings.txt") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(TempDirectory + "/Settings.txt")

    End If

    Dim colorConv As New ColorConverter
    Dim BackColorString As String
    BackColorString = colorConv.ConvertToString(BackColor)
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(TempDirectory + "/Settings.txt", True)
    file.WriteLine(BackColorString)
    file.Close()
```

When Openning:

```
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(TempDirectory + "/Settings.txt") Then
        Dim fileReader As String
        fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(TempDirectory + "/Settings.txt")
        Dim colorConv As New ColorConverter
        BackColor = colorConv.ConvertFromString(fileReader)
    End If
```

Comment: If you save a colour which isn't one of the named colours, it writes it in the format Color [A=99, R=99, G=19, B=255]. I have posted a way to parse that at [convert-a-string-to-a-system-color-in-net](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21651316/1115360), if that's any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Color myColor = new Color();

myColor = Color.AliceBlue;

string myColorSerialized = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(myColor);

MessageBox.Show("Color serialized is: " + myColorSerialized);

Color deserializedColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(myColorSerialized);

MessageBox.Show("Deserialized color is" + deserializedColor.ToString());
```

Use the following two methods for convert and save the color names without any problem in vb.net

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml

System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.IO

Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    Dim ThemePath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\settings\Theme.ini"
    Dim ThemeSaveSW = New StreamWriter(ThemePath, False)
    Dim BackgroundColor As String = Me.BackColor.ToArgb
    ThemeSaveSW.WriteLine(BackgroundColor)
    ThemeSaveSW.Flush()
    ThemeSaveSW.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ThemePath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\settings\Theme.ini"
    Dim ThemeReadSR = New StreamReader(ThemePath, False)
    Dim BackgroundColor As String = ThemeReadSR.ReadLine
    Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(BackgroundColor)
    ThemeReadSR.Close()
End Sub
```