# Why Does intellisense update like this

Tags: vb.net

I am creating some VB.NET modules in which work like so:
Project name:CommonLib
Namespace:uix
Module:color
I have the following:

```
Namespace uix
    Public Module color
        Private Property TextToColor As Dictionary(Of Drawing.Color, String)
        Sub New()

        End Sub
        Public Function SearchColor(color As String) As Drawing.Color
        End Function

    End Module
End Namespace
```

It allows the user to access like so:

```
CommonLib.uix.SearchColor()
```

Instead of:

```
CommonLib.uix.color.SearchColor()
```

Comment: It looks like you're asking about [Type Promotion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/type-promotion) -- Based on the `SearchColor()` definition, your dictionary should probably be a `Dictionary(Of String, Color)`

Comment: yes but even switchin the dictionary, it still shows incorrectly

Comment: What *shows incorrectly*? The Type promotion stuff is not related to the definition of the Dictionary, which is instead related to functionality of the `SearchColor()` method -- Did you read what's in the docs I've linked?

Comment: Yes so if I am correct i need to create another class of that name in the namespace to defeat the promotion?

Comment: You could rename `Namespace uix.color` (probably better `Namespace Uix.Color`, with also the Module renamed to `Color`) -- Not sure why you're using a Module, though

Comment: Incidentally, you might be interested in [Convert a String to a System.Color in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21650261/1115360).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how modules work. You don't have to qualify their members with the type name. I believe this was done for compatibility with VB6 code, which works the same way. Without that behaviour, a lot of upgraded VB6 code would not have worked without qualifying types being added.

If you don't want that behaviour then create a class with `Shared` members instead of a module.